# Upload image and convert to GrayScale using Flask

Tags: python, flask, image-processing, file-upload

I am a beginner to Flask and have a simple goal of creating a web app that takes an image as an input, then converts it to grayscale. Currently, the app creates an "images" folder, saves uploaded image to this folder, then displays in on a different page. When I try to add some sort of cv3 conversion on the "upload" file, I get a type error. Any thoughts on how I should implement this?

So far, my app.py looks like this:

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request, render_template, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("upload.html")

@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, 'images/')
    if not os.path.isdir(target):
            os.mkdir(target)
    else:
        print("Couldn't create upload directory: {}".format(target))

    for upload in request.files.getlist("file"):
        print("LOG: filename: {}".format(upload.filename))
        filename = upload.filename
        destination = "/".join([target, filename])
        print ("LOG: Accept incoming file:", filename)
        print ("LOG: Save it to:", destination)
        upload.save(destination)

    return render_template("display_image.html", image_name=filename)

@app.route('/upload/<filename>')
def send_image(filename):
    return send_from_directory("images", filename)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=4555, debug=True)
```

And my templates folder has a 2 html files:

upload.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Upload</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>File Uploader</h1>
        <form id="upload-form" action="{{ url_for('upload')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*"> 
            <input type="submit" value="send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

display_image.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head
>
<body>
    Uploaded
    <img src=" {{url_for('send_image', filename=image_name)}}">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, always share the complete traceback

Comment: Where is the CV3 conversion you mention please?